# VBA whats the best way to Increment in loop

Tags: vba, loops, excel, auto-increment

What would be a good way to increment each of my ranges for example I need x to copy Range B11:to G20 and paste it to C10 for the second loop. Each Variable has different increments.

Im using excel 2010

Any Help is appreciated cause I'm horrible with Visual Basic.

```
Dim i As Range, j As Range, k As Range
Dim x As Range, y As Range
Dim Num As Integer

Num = 94

Set x = Sheets("Sum Data").Range("B1:G10")
Set j = Sheets("PNA Physical Needs Summary Data").Range("C4")
Set i = Sheets("PNA Physical Needs Summary Data").Range("B4:B9")
Set k = Sheets("Sum Data").Range("A1")
Set p = Sheets("PNA Physical Needs Summary Data").Range("P3:P8")
Set e = Sheets("PNA Physical Needs Summary Data").Range("A4:A9")

Do
    Sheets("Sum Data").Select
    x.Copy
    Sheets("PNA Physical Needs Summary Data").Select
    j.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True

    p.Select
    Selection.Copy
    i.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Sheets("Sum Data").Select
    k.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("PNA Physical Needs Summary Data").Select
    e.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Num = Num - 1

 Loop Until Num = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Offset().  Eg:

```
Set x = x.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset)
```

Also - you don't need to select to copy ranges:

```
p.Copy i
```

is the same as:

```
p.Select     
Selection.Copy     
i.Select     
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Okay I changed the copy and paste, I have tried Offset in the loop but it gets stuck on certain pages and does not increment.                Do
        x.Copy
        Sheets("PNA Physical Needs Summary Data").Select
        j.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
         
        p.Copy i
        
        k.Copy e
        
        Num = Num - 1
        
        x = x.Offset(10, 0)
        j = j.Offset(5, 0)
        i = i.Offset(5, 0)
        k = k.Offset(10, 0)
        e = e.Offset(5, 0)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "gets stuck"? I notice you're not using "Set" when you move the ranges: need that.