# Have ranges of cell increment in different amounts VBA

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop, range

What are some ways I can make this work I have been trying to figure it out for hours.

I have tried using Offset in the loop but I haven't got it to work 
for example I used x = x.Offset(10,0) and i = i.Offset(5,0) etc.

```
  Sub Macro5()

    Dim i As Range, j As Range, k As Range
    Dim x As Range, y As Range
    Dim Num As Integer

    Num = 94

    Set x = Sheets("Sum Data").Range("B1:G10")
    Set j = Sheets("PNA Physical Needs Summary Data").Range("C4:L9")
    Set i = Sheets("PNA Physical Needs Summary Data").Range("B4:B9")
    Set k = Sheets("Sum Data").Range("A1")
    Set p = Sheets("PNA Physical Needs Summary Data").Range("P3:P8")
    Set e = Sheets("PNA Physical Needs Summary Data").Range("A4:A9")

    Do
        x.Copy
        j.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

        p.Copy i

        k.Copy e

        Num = Num - 1

     Loop Until Num = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Go back and check the comments on your original question: it's best to not start new questions too soon...

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA whats the best way to Increment in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793782/vba-whats-the-best-way-to-increment-in-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you are trying to do but the current routine successfully copies data from one set of ranges to another.

Have you omitted the Set from the statements to update x and i?  The following appear to work as you would expect

```
Set x = x.Offset(10,0)
Set i = i.Offset(5,0)
```

If omission of `Set` is not your problem, please expand your question to include your full code and the nature of the failure you experience.